# Coldfusion MX7 error with file upload

Tags: coldfusion

I am using coldfusion mx7 server. While upload an excel file with(97-2003) format, I am getting the following error:
 ***Unable to construct record instance, the following exception occured: null***

I am getting this error when I enters some data and save in my desktop with the format(97-2003) and after using a cfx tag to dump the uploaded data, I am getting this error. But if I just upload the template only without entering any data it will shows/dump the column name in template
Is there any way to upload the same excel file with MX7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with reading the file into the CFX tag, not with the upload.  I'd look there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you protecting the sheet/workbook after you enter data? Try without it. Also what OS is the CFMX 7 on?

Comment: thanks for the info, its a nice tip. I found one more thing. If we says yes to the alert box in excel to save in old format after entering data, keeps things fine else give error. But not sure about this alertbox presence while saving, sometime coming,sometimes just save option only ...another microsoft head-ache!!!